# Saving array of objects in Realm with Decodable

Tags: arrays, swift, database, realm, decodable

I've got a class which conforms to Decodable protocol (fetching data from API) and I would like to save it in the Realm database. Problem occurs when one of my properties is array (List). It says `Cannot automatically synthesize Decodable because List<Item> does not conform to Decodable`
What is the best way to bypass this problem? Realm only supports arrays of primitive types.

here is my class:

```
class PartValue: Object, Decodable {
    @objc dynamic var idetifier: Int = 0
    let items = List<Item>()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the long awaited conditional conformances implemented in Swift 4.1, you can simply declare `List` to conform to `Decodable` in case its `Element` conforms to `Decodable`.

```
extension List: Decodable where List.Element: Decodable {
    public convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.init()
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        let array = try container.decode(Array<Element>.self)
        self.append(objectsIn: array)
    }
}
```

To make this work for your specific case, you need to make sure that `Item` also conforms to `Decodable`.

If you also need `Encodable` conformance, simply extend `List` to support that as well.

```
extension List: Encodable where List.Element: Encodable {
    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.unkeyedContainer()
        try container.encode(contentsOf: Array(self))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dávid's solution didn't work for me completely. I had to tweak the solution instead by replacing `decoder.unkeyedContainer()` to `decoder.singleValueContainer()`, below is the solution.

```
extension List: Decodable where List.Element: Decodable {
    public convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.init()
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let array = try container.decode([Element].self)
        self.append(objectsIn: array)
    }
}
```